# Which method of object detection using OpenCV is best suited to changing environments?

Tags: opencv, object, detection

I am trying to identify the best OpenCV methods and implementations to identify objects that appear in a live camera feed. The implementation needs to be robust to changing light conditions and would ideally accommodate slight movement in the background (trees/clouds moving) without picking up too much noise.

The options I have tried so far include;

-Identifying the absolute pixel differences between an empty background frame and the current frame (works poorly if light conditions change or if camera jiggles)

-[Background subtraction](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html) (good for changing conditions but results in excessive noise)

-Have also thought about using edge detection, which would be unaffected by changing light conditions, and somehow compare object shapes to see what is new

I would ideally like an output that allows me to generate a bounding box for any objects that move around in the frame, with the background reference gradually changing over time to accommodate changing light conditions (or can a input frame be normalized for light so this has no effect?)

What would you recommend? I'm running OpenCV through Visual Studio 2017 in C++

Comment: In OpenCV - MOG2. But see first on bgslibrary: https://github.com/andrewssobral/bgslibrary

Comment: Background substraction methods of the OCV library are good for this kind of stuff. Of course it is not for free. If the performance is needed, this will need some optimalization. In case of noise as well some post processing, but it is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing course project on a similar project. I used several methods such as HSV/RGB threshold, Accumulative Difference Image, and MOG from OpenCV library.

For your case I would recommend Accumulative Difference Image which is very similar to MOG. Basically, you subtract consecutive frames from each other (previous from current), and then use threshold to convert to binary image. Then you can perform morphological operation on the binary image to enhance detection.

This method is relatively good for your case as it is not sensitive to reasonably slow changes of lighting and camera movements. However stationary object will not be detected.

In order to remove the noise you may want to Erode and then Dilate the binary image (play around with morphological operations).

Good luck!